# Are $3\mathbb {Z}$ and $9\mathbb {Z}$ ring isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

What I have so far is

Suppose $f: 3 \mathbb Z \rightarrow 9 \mathbb Z$ is a ring isomorphism.

Let $f(3)=9a  $

Now let us compute $f(9)$ two different ways:

$$f(9)= f(3+3+3)=f(3)+f(3)+f(3)=9a+9a+9a=27a$$

and

$$f(9)= f(3\times 3)=f(3)\times f(3)=9a\times 9a=81a^2 $$

Thus we have  $27a=81a^2$

So we have two integer solutionns of $a=1/3$ and $a=0$ which implies $f: 3 \mathbb Z \rightarrow 9 \mathbb Z$ is not an isomorphism.

I'm not completely sure if this proves it or if its even right. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to exhibit a mapping from $3\mathbb Z$ to $9\mathbb Z$ and prove that it is an isomorphism

Comment: I'm assuming these are groups you're dealing with. Right?

Comment: Can you describe an obvious 1-to-1 mapping between $3\mathbb Z$ and $9\mathbb Z$?

Comment: "Wrong proof": suppose that $3\Bbb Z$ and $9\Bbb Z$ are isomorphic groups, then $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$ are also isomorphic, a contradiction.

Comment: The tag "ring-theory", together with the equation $f(3 \times 3) = f(3) \times f(3)$ that occurs in the post, indicate that this question is not about group isomorphisms, but instead about ring isomorphisms.

Comment: And anyway, this looks a fine proof that $3\mathbb Z$ and $9 \mathbb Z$ are not isomorphic rings.

Comment: @LeeMosher it is about ring isomorphisms, I shall edit my question to clear this up. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your edited proof seems legit to me